# Uniform and Value-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14

I try to use value-initialization for members with value-initialization for constructors (I don't know if I really use the good terms...)

So... When I define:

```
struct A
{
  int a_;
};
```

I'm able to use:

```
A a{5};
assert(m.a_==5);
```

However, if I want to use the member brace initializer AND an initialization-list constructor

```
struct B
{
  int b_ {1};
};
```

This doesn't compile (c++14: http://ideone.com/MQ1FMU):

```
B b{2};
```

Here is the error:

```
prog.cpp:19:7: error: no matching function for call to 'B::B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
  B b{2};
       ^
prog.cpp:19:7: note: candidates are:
prog.cpp:10:8: note: constexpr B::B()
 struct B
        ^
prog.cpp:10:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
prog.cpp:10:8: note: constexpr B::B(const B&)
prog.cpp:10:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const B&'
prog.cpp:10:8: note: constexpr B::B(B&&)
prog.cpp:10:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'B&&'
```

What is the difference, concept-wise?
Many thanks!

Comment: Well I thought it was because `B` wasn't an aggregate, but it actually seems to meet the requirements as far as I can tell.  It's simply non-trivial.

Comment: Note that "C++14" on Ideone.com is g++-4.9.2, which is not C++14-compliant (as attested by this compile error!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under C++11 rules, `B` is not an aggregate type. C++11 [dcl.init.aggr]/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), **no *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members** (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

`B` only has a default constructor, and thus cannot be initialized from the *braced-initializer-list* `{2}`.

C++14 allows *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members in an aggregate. N4140 [dcl.init.aggr]/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

With fairly straight-forward semantics: fields for which there is no initializer specified are initialized from their *brace-or-equal-initializer*, if any, and otherwise initialized with `{}` [dcl.init.aggr]/7:

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* or, if there is no *brace-or-equal-initializer*, from an empty initializer list (8.5.4).

Your program is thus valid C++14 ([**DEMO**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IoUviio8T4DOUqUY)). Essentially, the prohibition of *brace-or-equal-initializer*s in C++11 was a mistake that C++14 corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I guess I should have tested with another c++14 compiler to be sure...